# How can I make a local repository of Ubuntu MAAS PXE Images?

Tags: repository, maas, pxe

Noob questions regarding Ubuntu MAAS:

- How do I make a local repository of Ubuntu MAAS PXE image?
- Is there any software to do it such as apt-mirror?
- Is there a page to download the image manually and store it on the
  Ubuntu MAAS controller?
- Where is the path to store the downloaded image?

I want to make it available locally for faster Ubuntu MAAS deployment and to save data usage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maas-import-pxe-files downloads operating system images, prepares them for use by MAAS nodes, and makes them available for nodes to boot over the network through TFTP, iSCSI, and SMB as appropriate.

Source: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/man/maas-import-pxe-files.8.html

About doing this manually, I don't if there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe Reyes, I guess I need to download the whole 1.5GB PXE images then. I also noticed that Ubuntu MaaS 1.5 on Trusty use squid proxy, and all client nodes internet go through that proxy.